# How should I keep track of a segment's movement in a high frame-rate snake game?

Tags: java

The more traditional game of snake has each segment taking the place of the segment in front of its previous position. The problem is that I am programming a "smooth" snake game in that the head is moving in minute amounts each frame.

Previously, I had `turningPoint`s that were created when the head moved. When each of the previous segments hit the point, they turned in the direction stored in the `turningPoint`. The problem with this is that I had to constantly bound for each segment for each `turningPoint`, there was accumulated error since the movement wasn't completely smooth (always a chance that the segment completely missed the point and did not turn), and that the segments were not "connected" but rather a lot of objects that happened to be moving next to each other.

My question is: How I would go about programming a smooth snake that turns properly effectively?

Comment: It depends on how you're snake is drawn or updated.  

Is he drawn in parts as a series of tiles or is he one continuous object(mesh)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the sound of things, you expect each segment to retrace the points the head went through, just several frames later. In which case, just make your snake data structure a list of the points the head has been at... then to draw the snake, loop through that list, skipping to say every 10th point, and draw a segment there.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you're having problem with the *model* (that is, the backend representation of your position/rotation data), and not the *view* (what's displayed on the screen), because usually smooth model movement translates well to smooth view movement.

Actually, this sounds like the perfect place for functional/lazy evaluation programming...

First, something for position/orientation:
(please note that `Vector` here isn't the collection class, but is more related to the mathematical concept, which is heavily used in graphics programming)

```
public final class PositionAndOrientation {
    public final Vector position;
    public final Vector orientation;

    public PositionAndOrientation(Vector position, Vector orientation) {
        this.position = position;
        this.orientation = orientation;
    }

    public PositionAndOrientation move(Vector direction) {
        return new PositionAndOrientation(position.add(direction), orientation);
    }

    public PositionAndOrientation rotate(Vector degrees) {
        return new PositionAndOrientation(position, orientation.add(degrees));
    }

}
```

Interface for adjustments/updates:

```
public interface AdjustPositionAndOrientation {
    PositionAndOrientation adjust(long stamp);
}
```

Starting position:

```
public final class StartingPositionAndOrientation 
                                      implements AdjustPositionAndOrientation {
    private final PositionAndOrientation starting;

    public StartingPositionAndOrientation(final PositionAndOrientation start) {
        starting = start;
    }

    public final PositionAndOrientation adjust(long stamp) {
        return starting;
    }
}
```

Move the segment:

```
public final class MovePosition implements AdjustPositionAndOrientation {
    private final AdjustPositionAndOrientation previous;
    private final Vector direction;
    private final long start;

    public MovePosition(long start, Vector direction, 
                                    AdjustPositionAndOrientation previous) {
        this.start = start;
        this.direction = direction;
        this.previous = previous;
    }

    public final PositionAndOrientation adjust(long stamp) {
        return previous.adjust(Math.min(stamp, start)).move(
                  direction.multiply(Math.max(stamp - start, 0)));
    }
}
```

Rotate the segment:

```
public final class RotatePosition implements AdjustPositionAndOrientation {
    private final AdjustPositionAndOrientation previous;
    private final Vector degrees;
    private final long start;

    public MovePosition(long start, Vector degrees, 
                                    AdjustPositionAndOrientation previous) {
        this.start = start;
        this.degrees = degrees;
        this.previous = previous;
    }

    public final PositionAndOrientation adjust(long stamp) {
        return previous.adjust(Math.min(stamp, start)).rotate(
                  degrees.multiply(Math.min(Math.max(stamp - start, 0), 90)));
    }
}
```

And finally the segment itself:

```
public final class Segment {
    private final Segment parent;
    private final long offset;
    private final AdjustPositionAndOrientation place;

    private Segment (Segment parent, long offset, AdjustPositionAndOrientation place) {
        this.parent = parent;
        this.offset = offset;
        this.place = place;
    }

    public static Segment startingAt(AdjustPositionAndOrientation place) {
        return new Segment(null, 0, place);
    }

    public static Segment connectTo(Segment parent, long offset) {
        return new Segment(parent, offset, null);
    }     

    public final PositionAndOrientation getPositionAndOrientation(long elapsed) {
        if (parent != null) {
            return parent.getPositionAndOrientation(elapsed - offset);
        } else {
            return place.adjust(elapsed);
        }

    }

}
```

This is only a rough sketch of course (and not tested), but the basic idea should get you started.  Notably, you're going to need a copy-constructor/factory for whenever you add a new `Adjust` to the chain, to reconstruct the segments.  However, the beauty of this approach is that I can create 'replays' simply by passing the parent segment the *final* (end) `Adjust` instance.

(Note: I've used long for the game clock, because that's what `Date` uses.  However, given that an `int` can hold enough milliseconds for a **week**, you could swap it in).

---

**EDIT:**

To 'move' the snake, you're actually going to want to *copy* it.  Adding a method like this to `Segment` should do the trick:

```
public final Segment addAdjutment(AdjustPositionAndOrientation place) {
    if (parent != null) {
        return connectTo(parent.addAdjustment(place), offset);
    } else {
        return startingAt(place);
    }
}
```

And call the method on the *tail*, **not** the head (as a side note, you'll only have to maintain external references to the tail of the snake, and it makes adding extra segments trivial - although this could be reversed, I think).  Please note that whatever adjustment you provide to the method should already encapsulate the one 'driving' the snake, or you'll need to add some sort of `copy(..)` method to the interface.  This means you'll either need to keep an external reference to the current adjustment, or add a recursive `get()` method to the snake (trivial to implement).

Comment: This is great. Very educational with the more complex class structure.

Comment: What does                                                       `public final PositionAndOrientation adjust(long stamp) {
        return previous.adjust(Math.min(stamp, start)).move(
                  direction.multiply(Math.max(stamp - start, 0)));
    }` mean? @X-Zero

Comment: I mean, what does the function multiply do as well? In the Vector class, because there are different ways to multiply vectors.

Comment: I was figuring that it was just multiplying all elements - increasing the magnitude of the vector.  That's what I'd expect a single-element argument for a vector to do...

Comment: I see. I am having trouble trying to get the snake as a whole to move: `if(currentTime - lastRefresh > REFRESH_RATE)
      {
  //code to move the snake goes here
             repaint();
             lastRefresh = currentTime;
         }` How should I traverse all of the segments and move each one? I'm sorry to question so much, I'm trying to understand this completely - it's very clever.

Comment: @EricThoma - updated.  Please note that this is _very_ rough, and may need to be modified (or tossed out).  I just thought that this was the perfect way to encapsulate this sort of 'follow the leader' behaviour.

Comment: Thanks! The only problem I am having is adding more segments onto the snake. The segments are added but when I use getPositionAndOrientation(currentTime) to access their PositionAndOrientation Vectors, it doesn't "go back in time" and so all of the segments are stacked on the head. Am I updating the head segment wrong?

Comment: I'm sorry to ask so many questions, but what is the start variable supposed to be in MovePosition? I can't seem to figure out what.